# Looking for a short zombie/comedy mini series

Tags: story-identification, zombie

I'm looking for a small (potentially independent/made for the web) mini series I've watched last year on Amazon Prime (Germany) centered around a fictional zombie apocalypse:

- Probably produced 2010 or later.
- Main protagonist is a young woman becoming infected (together with several others).
- Judging by the accents (English; no dub), it was most likely from Britain.
- Consists of 3 or 4 episodes, each around 10-15 minutes long.
- Viewers experience the story mostly from a zombie point of view.
- Zombies use simplified/plain English, calling other zombies "Friends" and humans/non-infected "Food".
- Core element of the story is the zombies learning new things:

  - At first they learn how to break their elbows to overcome rigor mortis.
  - Later on they discover how "food" turns into "friends" and they try to get other zombies to no longer hunt "food", because they'd be "friends".